# FFSERVER streaming to any network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, streaming, ffmpeg, ffserver

Is there some way to stream a media file using ffserver to any network from a local network as my ffserver is configured on subnet machine.

Right now I have it working only machines on the LAN (connected to my network) can view the file using http://localhost:8090/stream.mjpg , but I want people from the outside or any network also to be able to access it if they provide my machine address. Can anybody provide me some ideas on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to push the stream to a proper Internet-based server with a public IP address.  (Or expose your local machine as an Internet host, with some networking magic.)

Comment: thanks for your reply , you mean to say that the ffserver running on machine must have a public IP address , to be able to broadcast globally right ?

Comment: @user1191644: Yes.  Any server for that matter.  Web, streaming, mail, etc. services all must have a publicly available IP for it to be available to everyone.  *(This is a vey simple answer, and some folks might try to complicate the situation by mentioning proxy servers.  But at the end of the day you have to have that public IP.)*

Comment: thanku so much for your reply, I will have a public ip and get back to you incase any problem .